# Jquery infinite queue

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit new to jQuery and I am having trouble setting up a queue in this instance.

I am trying to do this: Upon mouseover the 1st queue entry is triggered. Then it **waits** until another mouseover to trigger the next queue entry. Cycle the queue infinitely.

http://jsfiddle.net/fChDX/

```
$("#header").mouseover(function() {
    var $shineCopy = $("#shine111").clone();
    $shineCopy.appendTo('body').animate({
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px",
        opacity: 0,
        "left": 0,
        "top":  100
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $shineCopy.appendTo('body').rotate({animateTo:180})
});
​
$("#header").mouseover(function() {
    var $shineCopy = $("#shine222").clone();
    $shineCopy.appendTo('body').animate({
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px",
        opacity: 0,
        "left": 0,
        "top":  200
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $shineCopy.appendTo('body').rotate({animateTo:180})
});

$("#header").mouseover(function() {
    var $shineCopy = $("#shine222").clone();
    $shineCopy.appendTo('body').animate({
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px",
        opacity: 0,
        "left": 0,
        "top":  300
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $shineCopy.appendTo('body').rotate({animateTo:180})
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you need help with?

Comment: You are just binding three event handlers, they will all be executed at the same time... if you want to change the behaviour upon consecutive events, you might want to have a look at this plugin I wrote: https://github.com/fkling/jQuery-Function-Toggle-Plugin

Comment: Felix, this is so elegant and beautiful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Felix's [jQuery Function Toggle Plugin](https://github.com/fkling/jQuery-Function-Toggle-Plugin), this was a piece of cake!

Updated jsFiddle to show the results.
http://jsfiddle.net/Wuq6M/

Comment: Very satisfying. Here it is in action! Hover over the header to see  it. http://www.herringbonebindery.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Have three functions defined seperately, have a javascript counter variable defined at the page level, and have your mouseover event both update the coutner variable and decide which function to call based on it.  If you want to make sure that you won't trigger the next one while the previous one is running, have a second "isrunning" var that you set to true on the start function and false on the remove function, and check that too.  Nothing fancy required.